# How to run SCrypt in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scrypt

Currently trying to use the [Triplesec Scrypt](http://keybase.github.io/triplesec/codo/index.html) to hash a password in scrypt in Javascript. However, I'm not entirely sure what parameters are supposed to be passed in. The constructor supposedly is

```
constructor({N, r, p, c, klass})
```

And I'm not sure what c and klass are supposed to be. Based on [the source code](https://github.com/keybase/triplesec/blob/master/browser/triplesec.js), I think I'm supposed to be using v2, where c is 64 and klass is XOR, but I'm not sure how to pass in XOR. Would anyone know how to use this function?

Comment: Am I missing something, or is this not a hash, but an encryption algorithm?

Comment: It works as both a hash and an encryption algorithm